# Printing the values falling in a range in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file that has 1000s of lines. Out of those lines, I have to print the line that has values lying in the range of 2.0L to 4.2L.
For example, this is one of the lines in the file:

```
"200","94","110","Rear-wheel drive","BMW `3.0L` 6 cylinder 315hp 330 ft-lbs Turbo","True","6","6 Speed Automatic Select Shift","17","Gasoline","25","Automatic transmission","2012 BMW 740Li Sedan","BMW","2012 BMW 7 Series","2012","315","330"
```

I need to print the lines which fall under the range mentioned above.
I have successfully managed to isolate the value using `cat cars.csv | awk '{print $3}'` which gives the output as:

```
3.5L
3.5L
3.7L
3.5L
3.7L
3.7L
3.7L
3.7L
3.5L
6.8L
```

But how exactly should I apply the condition in bash to restrict the values?

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please edit your samples and wrap them in CODE TAGS to make your question more clear, thank you.

Comment: What is the header of the CSV file?

Comment: Do you know that awk, by default, splits field by spaces-nonspace transitions? It doesn't seem very safe to rely on spaces in CSV fields 4 and 5.

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13. Actually, this is my first day on SO, so I'm still a noob. Lol. If you can explain where exactly I need to apply the tags then it'd be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Fravadona. Actually, I downloaded it from github, and I've no idea what the header is.

Comment: @steffen, yes, I'm aware that it takes spaces as the column separator by default. And as you have mentioned, it's not very safe to rely on it, but for this question, it works fine as all the data follow the same pattern.

Comment: @SaikatSarkar The header, when there is one, is the first line of the CSV. It gives names to the columns

Comment: Oh!! I see. It's this @Fravadona

*"Dimensions.Height","Dimensions.Length","Dimensions.Width","Engine Information.Driveline",**"Engine Information.Engine Type"**,"Engine Information.Hybrid","Engine Information.Number of Forward Gears","Engine Information.Transmission","Fuel Information.City mpg","Fuel Information.Fuel Type","Fuel Information.Highway mpg","Identification.Classification","Identification.ID","Identification.Make","Identification.Model Year","Identification.Year"*

So **Engine Information.Engine Type** happens to be the specific column here

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `cat` here `cat cars.csv | awk '{print $3}'` as GNU `AWK` can handle file reading itself, just pass filename as argument that is

```
awk '{print $3}' cars.csv
```

If this does output

```
3.5L
3.5L
3.7L
3.5L
3.7L
3.7L
3.7L
3.7L
3.5L
6.8L
```

then you should be able to select lines with values in 2.0L to 4.2L range by doing

```
awk '$3>=2.0&&$3<=4.2' cars.csv
```

Explantion: condition is given but not action, therefore all lines where conidition is met will be printed. When comparing against numerical value GNU `AWK` parse longest prefix which does represent number - in this case everything before `L`. `&&` is logical AND. If you want to know more about string to number conversion read [Strings And Numbers (The GNU Awk User's Guide)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html)

Comment: This worked perfectly fine. I did not know that awk can print the output directly, I thought we need to read the file using cat and then pipe it to pass the input to it. And thanks for sharing the Awk User's Guide as well. I learned new things today. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To output the lines with 2.0L to 4.2L anywhere in the line try `grep -E "[23].[0-9]L|4.[012]L" cars.csv` where `-E` tells [grep](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) to use an extended regular expression.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, this worked as well. Thank you. I'd have given all of you an upvote but my reputation is too low

Answer (score 0):

You can cause awk to interpret the 3th field as a number by using `$3+0`. Then you can use an arithmetic function to filter the range of values like so:

```
cat cars.csv | awk '{if ($3+0 >= 2.0 && $3+0 <= 4.2) print $3}'
```

Comment: We can make a conditional statement inside Awk!! Bash is really quite weird.